# Adding private reviews page to a Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I've spent quite a bit of time looking through tutorials, and plugins, and I am struggling to figure this out.

Here's the goal:

1. Take an existing WP site.
2. Add a "write a review" page which will include a few form fields (star rating, comment, name, etc)
3. If rating is high, invite user to share on Yelp, Facebook, etc
4. Review is saved to DB, and site admin receives email that new comment is ready
5. Site admin logs into site to review comments. This interface has CRUD options, plus allows admin to add notes about customer's review.

I'm least concerned about #3. Most concerned about saving to DB and retrieving.

Comments will never be shown publicly.

**Here are my questions / problems:**

1. I looked at custom fields, but that seems more suited for post meta data than for individual reviews.
2. Is there a simple way I can re-use the WP admin dashboard to get my reviews? Could I hack it as private comments with some extra form fields that then all show up in the WP comments section?
3. Does it make more sense to use plugins or write from scratch, or a combination? I see tons of plugins but most don't do exactly what I want.
4. Should I use a separate DB, or just have a new table in the WP database?
5. Any general recommendations for specific plugins or for the general approach to use?

Thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to relate two pages to each other

1. The Article Page
2. The Review Page

You can do this by creating a new page (see [this from Tom McFarlin](https://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-create-a-post-in-wordpress/)) and as part of the page you have created include a meta field that relates back to the original post, or use Advanced Custom Fields Relationship Field. To create the new page you can have a form that posts the elements you want such as title and content.

So to answer your enumerated questions

1. I suggest a new related page rather than a load of meta fields. This would give you all the features you want to attach to such a page, even star ratings for a post
2. These would then show up directly in the wordpress admin and it would be relatively easy to write an admin box for the original posts to show all reviews related via a query
3. What you are asking to do is probably beyond the scope of most plugins, you might find plugins that can help in the work such as Advanced Custom Fields for relationships but I think that a lot is custom work
4. The wordpress database can work fine for this. Using existing posts/pages or a custom post type would give you a massive leg up
5. General approach is as I put at the start. Plugins: Possibly [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for the [related posts](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) but I think you would have to code the creation of the review (possibly as a custom post type) and then add the relationship using code.